# How to set tab order with promoted widgets?

Tags: qt, qwidget, qt-designer, tab-ordering

I have the following design

```
QWidget
  QFrame promoted to FooComponent 
    QLineEdit a (internal tab order 1)
    QLineEdit b (tab order 2)
  QLineEdit c (tab order 1)
```

In Qt Creator (designer) I can not set a tab order for the `FooComponent`. So when I activate the `QWidget` I see the cursor in `c`, but I would want it to be in `a`.

How can I handle tab order with cascaded components?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [`setFocuProxy`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFocusProxy). In `FooComponent`, set the focus-proxy to the first child widget in its internal tab-order.

Then in Qt Designer, change the `focusPolicy` of the promoted `QFrame` to `TabFocus`, and reset the tab-order so that it is in the right place in the sequence.

Comment: Very good hint. It works, only the initial focus is not in the first field for some reasons. I have tried `setFocus` but it does not work. But the tab order itself works, only it does not start with the "field 1".

Comment: @HorstWalter. I created an example using the design in your question, and it all works fine for me. Are you sure you've set the tab-order in `FooComponent`, and is the focus-proxy set to "field 1"? If your real design is more complicated, please post the ui file.